save file on local host in windows visual studio code
I have opened a python code from a Linux based Raspberry Pi (with samba and windows explorer). But when I try to save the file, there is an error message; Failed to save 'home.py': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator.. I already tried it as an administrator.
Thanks

Code, I want to save

Error message

so you're running vs code on windows and trying to save a file on your window machine? If that's the case then I can't see how it's Pi related...
